# Update single dependency in IntelliJ based on gradle build

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

Is it possible to get IntelliJ to update a single dependency rather than have to refresh all dependencies via the "Refresh all Gradle projects" button in the Gradle side tab?

The reason I ask is that a full refresh takes several minutes on our project (Long enough for me to write this SO question!) and I just want to update a dependency on another project I am updating locally.

Comment: Still looking for answers! It's frustrating to update/refresh all dependencies even though only one has changed. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunatelly, it's not possible due to the Gradle architecture. We can't get partial data using the API and the full build has to be run to get the actual state of the dependencies.

Comment: makes it really hard to use the gradle stuff because every little gradle change takes a long time to complete freezing development effort. i start working from 2 laptops to avoid the issue.